# IBMCloudCodeHybrid SDK always going to onFailure on Android

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, hybrid, ibm-cloud

I am developing a mobile **hybrid** application on BlueMix. I have just added the necessary tools by following the instructions [here](https://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/hybrid#set-up-worklight).

Server Node.js code (dependencies and ibmconfig variable are correctly set):

```
app.get(ibmconfig.getContextRoot() + '/hello', function(req,res){
    res.send('World');
});
```

Hybrid mobile application code:

```
var setup = {
    applicationId:'<applicationId>',
    applicationRoute:'<applicationRoute>',
    applicationSecret:'<applicationSecret>'
};

IBMBluemix.initialize(setup).then(function(config){
    return IBMCloudCode.initializeService();
}).then(function(cloudcode){
    cloudcode.get("/hello").then(function(data){
        alert(data);
    }, function(err){
        alert("[ERROR] " + err);
    });
});
```

Sorry for removing all none necessary stuff. My issue is that this code is actually working on iOS devices, but not on Android. Meaning for iOS I get the `World` alert, but for Android I get `[ERROR] "{\"code\":200,\"data\":\"World\"}"` alert. And whatever I try to do (for instance setting the content-type header), I always go to the **onFailure** function on **Android** devices. 
What I found out is that the server response on Android is understood as a string and not a JSON, so I changed the IBMCloudCodeHybrid.js:line 687 and added

```
if (response.constructor === 'abc'.constructor) {
      response = JSON.parse(response);
}
if (_.has(response, "code") && _.has(response, "data") && response.code === 200) {
      response = response.data;
} else {
      defer.reject(response);
}
```

so that whenever a string is received, it will be converted to JSON. 
And that worked for me.
**So** my questions are, do I have to that in order to make it work on Android? Or is there a proper way to do that/I am doing something wrong ?
Or is something wrong with the Bluemix SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

the first item you should check is the content-type header sent to device.
For json it should be 'application/json' (or 'application/javascript' for JSONP), very often libraries are checking it to choose the right parser.